# DateTimepicker in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to show date and time picker. I googled many times but not getting anything. I download the files from the "keduoi.com" and used in mu project but its not working properly showing only textfield. I am trying from [this link](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datetimepicker/index.html).

Here is code:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LaterTime_Pick_up.aspx.cs" Inherits="LocationBasedTaxiServices.LaterTime_Pick_up" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="example" class="k-content">
                <div id="to-do">
                        <input id="datetimepicker" style="width:200px;" />
                </div>
            <script type="">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element
                    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
                        value: new Date()
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <style scoped> 
                #to-do {
                    height: 52px;
                    width: 221px;
                    margin: 30px auto;
                    padding: 91px 0 0 188px;
                    background: url('../../content/web/datepicker/todo.png') transparent no-repeat 0 0;
                }
            </style>
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

It's showing only textfield.

Comment: You are missing js/kendo.all.min.js link in your code

Comment: u are rite... but i have not file for this

Comment: You should probably buy it :) or use its 30 days trial.

Comment: js/kendo.all.min.js is not available in the folder which I download from the <http://kendo.com>

Comment: this is my project work.... I cant buy it or cant use it on trial basis.....  @voo;(

Comment: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/DateTimePicker-control-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Example.aspx   ||||
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker

Comment: @Faiza are you working on JQuery..???

Comment: @Faiza there are many other alternatives, which are free. Personaly I use ajaxcontroltoolkit calendar extender control. But you can search for some others. They are not worse then kendo, belive me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure unless you can tell exactly what error you are getting. But if you have not added js file then go ahead and do it first.

There are different plans available to get kendo ui. **[Refer This](http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx)**

There is documentation by kendo for using datepicker in asp.net application.

**[Link Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/datetimepicker/overview)**

Comment: I am not working in mvc and not using razor... as I am new I havenot any idea for this.....

Comment: I am working with Kendo UI web...... others are on trial basis.... and trying for this ...... but cant get andy thing other than text field @Milind Anantwar

Comment: @faiza: http://www.kendoui.com/download/download-kendo.aspx?pId=KENDOUIWEBGPL&lict=3

fill the form given in left side and your download will start after that.

Answer (score 2):

You must include the Javascript for kendoui.

```
<script src='xxxx/kendo-uixxx.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

kendo.all.min.js is missing in your code.

You also can use jQuery.UI, it sometimes easier for beginners to start building client interfaces with jQuery.

- jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/
- jQuery UI Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/